# What's the difference between a null set and an empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From my notes, I understand that an empty set always has a null size (is this different from saying that it has a size = 0?).

What are then examples of non-empty null sets?

Thanks for your time.

--- Edit: There seems to be some conceptual difference. Wikipedia also has 2 different articles (which I mostly don't understand :-) ) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set).

Comment: IIRC, null set is the same thing as empty set, and is denoted by $\emptyset$. Basically, null set is a theoretical construction used to denote a set which has no elements. This construction is useful in many cases, mostly in proofs relating to set-theoretic problems. I summon Asaf Karagila here to answer this problem in full detail. ;)

Comment: In measure-theoretic context, using the term "null set" can cause confusion; for it can refer to a set of measure zero.

Comment: If a null set is defined as a set of measure zero as in the Wiki page you cited, then an empty set is a null set. But the converse is not true; consider $\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In analysis and measure theory, the term *null set* is also used to denote a set which has "size" zero, but in that case, size means a different thing. For instance, on the real line, it is customary to use *length* (at least in naïve settings). So the interval $[-3, 5]$ has size $8$ and the set $(2, 3)\cup [5, 7]$ has size $3$.

In this setting, examples of non-empty null-sets are:

- Single-element sets, like $\{5\}$.
- In fact, any countable set, like $\Bbb Q$
- The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)

So whether there is a difference between the phrases "empty set" and "null set" depends entirely on the context.

Comment: @Gloomy Yes, or at least it has to _contain_ an interval somewhere. For instance, $\{2,3,10\}\cup(5,6)$ is not a null set, and neither is $\Bbb Q\cup[0,1]$. And then you have the unmeasurable sets, which cannot be given a size in any consistent way. Constructing one depends on a leap of faith called the axiom of choice. Basically, if you're fine with the axiom of choice, you can make a collection $C_i\subseteq[0,1)$, where there are countably infinitely many $C_i$, and they are all equally big. Whatever length you try to assign each of them, they cannot sum up to $1$, so it cannot be done.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the context.

In the context of set theory, the null set is the empty set. And that's the end of it.

In the context of measure theory, analysis, or probability, a null set is a set whose measure is $0$. For example in the usual Borel measure, finite sets are null sets; countable sets are null sets; and even some uncountable sets (e.g. the Cantor set) are null sets. But they are certainly not empty.

In that context, a null set is a set which is completely uninteresting "for practical purposes" and we can ignore safely ignore it if we choose to. So this statement is more general than just "empty".

Note, however, that if you define an equivalence relation "$A\sim B$ if and only if $A\mathbin{\triangle}B$ is a null set", then the null sets are exactly those equivalent to the empty set.