# Proof that ${\bf 1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x) $ (indicator function of the set of rational numbers) is not Riemann-Integrable over [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

We just saw the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem which says that a function is Riemann-integrable if the set of discontinuities has Null size.

The indicator function being defined by

[image]

I deduce that the function is equal to 0 over the real axis except for a infinite (but countable) amount of points in which it is equal to 1.

Since the size of a set of countable points is Null (see [This Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533260/whats-the-difference-between-a-null-set-and-an-empty-set/)), I would deduce that $$I\!I_{\mathbb{Q}}(x) $$
Is indeed Integrable - where is my mistake?

Comment: It **nowhere** continuous.

Comment: It is discontinuous as the (countable number of) rational points but also at the (uncountable number of) ________ points. You fill in the gap.

Comment: I love the pedagogic approach but I fail to see what you mean? If it's "irrational" points, then aren't they continuous between 2 rational points?

Comment: Take any real number $a$, and show that your function is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: The set of discontinuities is every single point in $[0,1]$ --- the set of discontinuities is uncountable.